# Fog not uploading entire file to S3

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3, fog

I'm using a ruby script to generate an html page that I'm uploading to s3. My amazon bucket is configured to work as a static website, and the html page my script is generating is the index page.

I've created a couple of models to build a connection to s3 using the fog gem, generate the html page, and then push it up to s3.

When I use the script to push the file up to s3, I don't get any errors, but only half the file gets uploaded. It happens regardless of file size. I inevitably wind up with about 15 rows missing from the html table I generated.

The relevant code from my FogManager model is this:

```
def connect
  @connection = Fog::Storage.new({
    provider:              'AWS',
    aws_access_key_id:     AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
    aws_secret_access_key: AWS_SECRET_KEY,
    persistent:            true
  })
end

def locate_directory
  @directory = @connection.directories.get(DIRECTORY)
end

def upload_report_page(index_file)
  file = @directory.files.get(index_file)
  file.body = File.open(index_file)
  file.acl = 'public-read'
  file.save
end
```

My script looks something like:

```
filename = "index.html"

s3 = FogManager.new
s3.connect
s3.locate_directory

# code for generating the html page

s3.upload_report_page(filename)
```

All of the code works, but the whole html file isn't getting uploaded to s3.

I'm using the latest version of fog (1.15.0) with ruby 2.0.0p0

I've been able to manually go into irb and establish an s3 connection, locate the file, and upload the new one. I use these commands:

```
require 'fog'

connection = Fog:Storage({provider: 'AWS', 
                          aws_access_key_id: 'xxx', 
                          aws_secret_access_key: 'xxx',
                          persistent: true})

directory = connection.directories.get('my_directory')

file = directory.files.get('index.html')
file.body = File.open('index.html')
file.acl = 'public-read'
file.save
```

When I upload the file this way, it works properly, and the whole file gets uploaded, but it defeats the purpose of having the script.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Nothing obvious jumping out at me I fear. I presume that the index file itself didn't change in between the two commands you ran? Otherwise it is pretty puzzling as the two scripts seem to me to be equivalent.

Comment: Yeah, I made sure to check that. The index file was the same in both cases; I didn't regenerate it before manually uploading it in irb. I was more than a little baffled by this, since it's literally the same code. But the script is consistent in always missing a large chunk of the file, while the manual upload in irb always gets the whole file up to s3.

Comment: Try executing your script prefacing it with `EXCON_DEBUG=true`. This should spit out the raw HTTP traffic to Amazon. It might give you a little more of any idea of what is actually happening.

Comment: Nothing jumps out at me when I do that. The response code is 200, and no errors are showing. Is there anything in specific I should be looking for within the excon request/response?

Comment: Hmm. When you run the script (vs irb) how are you running it? Is it possible that you are hitting bundled versions of gems or something in one case or the other? ie getting different versions that expected?

Comment: The script I just run from the command line. It isn't part of a rails app or anything. I checked and both are using the same version of fog. I was able to make it work by pulling out the code for generating the html page and putting it into its own script that I run before the s3 upload script. I don't know why that made a difference, but it works; the whole file makes it up to s3.